# Can we get the cost of a singe lambda function using GetCostAndUsageWithResources?

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli, aws-cost-explorer

I am trying to find the cost of a single lambda function. The document on [GetCostAndUsageWithResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsageWithResources.html) doesn't specify which services arns or ids we can put while filterting through "RESOURCE_ID".

I tried the following code using boto3's [get_cost_and_usage_with_resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce/client/get_cost_and_usage_with_resources.html) but all I recieved was zero cost being incurred.

```
import boto3

ce_client = boto3.client("ce")

response = ce_client.get_cost_and_usage_with_resources(
    TimePeriod={"Start": <some-start-date>, "End": <some-end-date>,
    Granularity="DAILY",
    Filter={
        "Dimensions": {
            "Key": "RESOURCE_ID",
            "Values": [<my-lambda-arn>]
        }
    },
    Metrics=["UnblendedCost"],
)

print(response)
```

So, what I want to ask are these two questions:

1. Can GetCostAndUsageWithResources be used to find the cost of single lambda function?
2. If not, then, how can we get the cost of a single lambda function by using its name or arn?

Comment: Personally, I tag every service with the key as the project name and the value being a unique identifier for that particular instance, lambda, etc...  There may be a better way, but this is what works for me.  Tags don't apply right away and I don't recall if they take into account any data from before the tag was applied as I normally tag on creation.  Lambda specific example being key: MyProject | value: Lambda:MyCoolServerlessFunction.  Then just pass the `Tag` object in the request body.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/latest/userguide/ce-resource-daily.html

Comment: @KeithRusso Thanks for the information. We do that as well but also wanted to see if we can get the cost of a single lambda function programmatically using the function's name or arn in case the functions were not tagged.

Comment: @jellycsc When I go to the cost explorer preferences page to enable the daily granularity, the services list over there doesn't have 'Lambda' in my case. Can you confirm if it is the same for you?